# Python FTP can't finish commands

Tags: python, ftplib

Long and short is I'd like to use a python script to write then transfer a text document to a remote server. This is the early stages and the writing shouldn't be the concern so for sake of argument the base code is below:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP
f = FTP('ip address')
f.login('user','pass')
f.cwd('location to deposit file')
f.retrlines('LIST')
os.chdir("C:\")
filename = 'filename.txt'
f.storlines('STOR ' + filename, open(filename, 'rb'))
f.quit()
```

This sequence should connect, list the text files in the directory, and then deposit the file there. **This code works on my computer.**

The issue arises when I remote onto a different computer that uses IronPython 2.7.1. On this system with this compiler the connection appears to work but the compiler gets (for lack of better words) "hung up". It will never move past certain requests.

I've included an image of it just "waiting".

Internet, help me.

[image: a thing that may make sense...]

Comment: Does the other computer have network connectivity on the relevant port to the target ftp server? Does the target accept connections from the problematic server? This sounds like a network/firewall issue.

Comment: This probably requires someone with a bit more expertise to answer...
What I can say, is when I do this line by line with the ftp tool set_debuglevel(2) it does say it connects, I can get the .getwelcome() to give confirmation. So from the layman that I am it does seem like I have "some connection" to this... but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but often FTP gets stuck because it tries to use the *active* mode (sendport commands) when a firewall is configured to only allow the *passive* mode. You should try to explicitely use the passive mode (or active if passive blocks).

Comment: Good suggestion; I've tried it in ".set_pasv('True')". Results were the same; it get's hung up and sits there for around half an hour. I've finally let it sit there till I get a result and that is 

"ftplib.error_temp: 426 Data Connection: Error 0."
I don't know what this means and related searches don't appear to be related to my purpose/situation...

Comment: The line `os.chdir("C:\")` won't work, as you're opening a string literal without closing it – you need to write `\\` whenever you want a backslash in a string, i.e. `os.chdir("C:\\")`. I guess probably this code is not exactly the same as the code you're running, but I thought I'd check just in case this is causing your problem.